# Async/Await Web API call in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to do a async/await Web API Post in Global.asax to not block the application from loading when doing the Rest-api-post.

But the application never starts and things will go mutch faster when not doing it async. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var somePostValue = myJsonString();  
        RunAsync(somePostValue).Wait();
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync(string postValue)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56789/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MyApi", postValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your just waiting synchronously on the asynchronous operation anyway, which is going to behave just like the synchronous version, but with the added overhead of setting up the asynchronous operation.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the reply. So what are you saying? Is it not possible to do a api call asynchronous in global.asax?

Comment: I'm saying you're not actually doing it asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy Ok. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Don't synchronously wait for the operation to finish.

Comment: @Servy Is it better to change `RunAsync` to void-type and don't do it async at all?

Comment: If you want to start the asynchronous operation and have the program continue on despite the fact that it hasn't finished, yes.  If anyone is going to need to know when the operation has finished, if it finished successfully, etc. then it shouldn't be a `void` method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to register the *Async() methods with the proper `HttpApplication` `AddOn*()` callbacks. This avoids deadlocks (which I'd be surprised if you weren't having them) A more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42007294/1754346

Comment: Unfortunately the `AddOn*Async` methods are all per-request. There is no `AddOnApplicationStartupAsync` method.

Answer (score -2):

Since it doesn't look like you are doing anything with the response, instead of waiting for the task,

```
RunAsync(somePostValue).Wait();
```

you could fire and forget it it like so:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunAsync(somePostValue));
```

Comment: `RunAsync(somePostValue)` is enough for  *fire and forget*