# Call Async Method from Session_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

How can I call an **async** method from `Session_Start` in Global.asax ?

Global.asax:

```
    protected async Task Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Session.Timeout = 10;

        // Do some asynch work
        await repository.SetStatsInfo(System.DateTime.Now);            
    }
```

async method:

```
    public async Task SetStatsInfo(DateTime time)
    {
        using (ApplicationDBContext db = new ApplicationDBContext())
        {
            // Do stuff (update visitors counter in db) ..

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
    }
```

I can run it all synchronously (define `void Session_Start` etc.) which is working, but would prefer the async way so that hitting the db is not blocking.

Running like this with 'async Task' for `Session_Start`, the code is not executed,
breakpoints inside `session_start` are not hit.

Comment: Chris said it correctly. There is no reason for this to be async, as it simply doesn't make sense. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38956850/2410379

Comment: @DavidPine But what should we do when we need to consume an API that is only available as a `async Task<T>` call? Stephen Clearly has beaten into us that we must never call `GetAwaiter()` or `.Result` because of the risk of deadlocks - so how can an ASP.NET Application's `Global` `Application_Start` method safely call an async method?

Comment: `Session_Start` is an event handler. It clearly makes sense to be able to handle events asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods like `Session_Start` in Global.asax are special. You can't just arbitrarily define new ones. The framework runs the one it's programmed to run, and no async versions are provided. As a result, no async version will ever be run.

However, it doesn't really make sense to be async anyways. The Global.asax methods are called at startup and shutdown of the App Pool. As a result, it doesn't make sense to give up the operating thread at any point, because nothing else can happen until it completes its work anyways.

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but based on the comment in your code, it doesn't sound like this is the right place to be doing it anyways. Again, this code runs only once, not per request. If you want something to happen per request, look into something like an action filter.

Comment: As you noted, the intention is to update the site visitors count in the db each time a new session has started (running sync, as I now understand). 
But why isn't Session_Start an appropriate place for that ?

Comment: Because Global.asax runs only when the App Pool starts or shutdowns. In the meantime, any number of requests, for any number of different users happen. If you were to add some sort of visitor tracking logic to Session_Start, it would only happen once when the App Pool starts, and the App Pool could conceivably not restart for hours, days, or even weeks, depending on how it's configured and the state of the server. Obviously, that's not going to give you very relevant info.

Comment: Are you referring to `Application_Start` ? `Session_Start` event is fired every time a new session is created, as mentioned in:  [http://forums.asp.net/t/1230163.aspx?What+s+the+difference+between+Application_Start+and+Session_Start+in+Global+aspx+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1230163.aspx?What+s+the+difference+between+Application_Start+and+Session_Start+in+Global+aspx+)

Answer (score 12):

From what I understand, ASP has a designated thread that is the ONLY thread that has access to the `HttpContext.Current` object, and in turn, access to the Session
(`HttpContext.Current.Session`) much like the UI thread in windows applications. Therefore, performing a `.Wait()` or `.Result` in Session_Start callback will give you unknown results and/or deadlock the process.

There seems to be numerous ways to govern a Task's thread of execution, the primary one being specifying your task to run with a certain synchronization context via the TaskScheduler class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx#Sync

However, since the Task class was designed to implement `IAsyncResult`, which comes from the APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) pattern, this makes Task backwards compatible with older APM pattern code (Which from what I understand ASP was originally built on). It takes a bit of integration work, though https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2011/10/04/the-asynchronous-programming-models/ (Standard APM).

.Net 4.5 introduced a nice Task wrapper (`EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper`) to perform asynchronous actions utilizing the APM-style `HttpApplication` was built to support. It meets all the requirements to access the Session object, and execute correctly in the `HttpApplication`:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    //EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper Wraps the task call in an APM-style BeginEventHandler, EndEventHandler
    var wrapper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(AsyncSessionStart);
    this.AddOnAcquireRequestStateAsync(wrapper.BeginEventHandler, wrapper.EndEventHandler);
}

private async Task AsyncSessionStart(Object sender, EventArgs evtArgs)
{       
    //The only caveat is we have to check IsNewSession to see if it was created in this call
    //This doesn't need to be applied for other AddOn*Async wire-ups
    if (!Session.IsNewSession)
        return;

    await doSomethingAsync();
}

//I recall seeing something that for session state to be active, this callback has to be declared, even if empty
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Synchronous session
}
```

Comment: FYI: The empty Session_OnStart method is required for pages with ReadOnly sessions because the SessionStateModule checks whether the Session_OnStart sync handler is defined to force save of session state even on read only sessions: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/SessionStateModule.cs,1292

Comment: A note on this: the [`HttpApplication.Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.session) property throws an exception if there is no session (which will happen when getting bundled resources, for example). So you're better off doing the check with `if (HttpContext.Current?.Session?.IsNewSession != true) return;`

Comment: I have just implemented this technique to implement an async call to a gitlab service to retrieve the version in Global.asax.cs.

I wanted to confirm the speculation of the OP about having to have a Session_Start method - I already had one but it still did not work, but I noticed mine was parameterless, as I was not using the sender or EventArgs. I added them in the signature and presto - all is working.

I also had to include the null check on HttpContext.Current?.Session - it seems the method was being called three or four times on load, only once with a Session which was instantiated.